# Updating an ArrayList that contains multipe datatypes

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to update an array list and running into errors that I can't seem to shake (having reviewed a number of similar questions here).

Main Class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Player> PLAYERS = new ArrayList<Player>();
    PLAYERS.add(new Player("char1", 10, "A"));
    PLAYERS.add(new Player("char2", 20, "B"));
```

Then late, as the result of a loop (which is running without issue), I'm trying to update one of the above entries with-

```
PLAYERS.set(index, ("char1", variable, variable));
```

That last line is flagging errors
[image: shown here.]

Player Class

```
public class Player {
public String character;
public int money;
public String reference;

Player(String character, int money, String reference){
    this.character = character;
    this.money = money;
    this.reference = reference;
}
```

}

I've tried a few different way of updating, including using getters/setters, and having the different objects in the array being variables in their own right, but can't seem to work it out.

Comment: `PLAYERS.set(index, ("char1", variable, variable));` is not valid Java syntax. What are you expecting it to do?  Java is not Javascript.

Comment: Try `PLAYERS.set(index, new Player("char1", variable, variable));`. This will put a new `Player` instance into your list at index `index`.

Answer (score 2):

```
PLAYERS.set(index, ("char1", variable, variable));
```

Is not valid Java syntax.  You most likely mean

```
PLAYERS.set(index, new PLAYER("char1", variable, variable));
```

Also, please adhere to standard Java naming conventions: `PLAYERS` should be `players`.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance; I've updated per your instructions, and it seems to have resolved some though not all of the problem.

I replaced PLAYERS with Players throughout, and the particular line in questions now reads as:

    Players.set(0, new Player("char1", variable, variable));

While the flag now states:

cannot find symbol
symbol: variable Players
location: class [My Main Class]

Answer (score 0):

Your ArrayList **doesn't** contain multiple data types. It holds objects of Player and only Player type, and you appear to be trying to over-complicate things. You simply get your Player from the ArrayList and then modify it.

```
Player p = players.get(i);
p.setName("foo");
p.setMoney(50);
```

Comment: You're correct on this, of course, and this put me on the right track. Once I realized that there was only one datatype in the array (itself containing more information), I was able to set about correcting how to edit a part of an entry using getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is correct. It doesn't know what you mean by ("char1", variable, variable) . 
Try updating it with new Player("char1", variable, variable);